# Devise and Simple_form error in association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, simple-form

I'm having trouble creating Sign up to my rails app, I'm using Devise and Simple_form, I have 2 models (User and department), users belongs_to :department and department has_many :users, i get an error when i try to sign up saying that department must exits.

**devise/registrations/new.html.erb**

```
    <h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :username, required: true, autofocus: true %>
    <%= f.input :email, required: true %>
    <%= f.input :password, required: true, hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length) %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true %><br>
    <%= f.association :department %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

**user.rb** :

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, :username
  belongs_to :department
  has_and_belongs_to_many :courses
end
```

**department.rb** :

```
class Department < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
  has_many :courses
end
```

I populated the departments table using seeds.rb and checked through mysql console.

**schema.rb** :

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180502071349) do

  create_table "courses", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1" do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "description"
    t.bigint "department_id"
    t.string "instructor_name"
    t.integer "credit_hours"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["department_id"], name: "index_courses_on_department_id"
  end

  create_table "departments", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1" do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "enrollments", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1" do |t|
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.bigint "courses_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["courses_id"], name: "index_enrollments_on_courses_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_enrollments_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1" do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "username", default: "", null: false
    t.bigint "department_id"
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["department_id"], name: "index_users_on_department_id"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
    t.index ["username"], name: "index_users_on_username", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "courses", "departments"
  add_foreign_key "enrollments", "courses", column: "courses_id"
  add_foreign_key "enrollments", "users"
  add_foreign_key "users", "departments"
end
```

**migration files**:

```
class CreateDepartments < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :departments do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
# frozen_string_literal: true

class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""
      t.string :username,           null: false, default: ""
      t.references :department, foreign_key: true

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    add_index :users, :username,             unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
class CreateCourses < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :courses do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description
      t.references :department, foreign_key: true
      t.string :instructor_name
      t.integer :credit_hours

      t.timestamps
    end
    create_table :enrollments do |t|
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true
      t.references :courses, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

P.S., I'm just starting out with rails and thanks for your help.

[Error screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzBBJ.png)

Comment: Has the department table at least one record?

Comment: yes, It has 2 entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Devise doesn't know anything about your none standard `department_id` field and filters it as unpermitted parameter.

Create your own registrations controller (which extends Devise) and then customize these methods:

```
def sign_up_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :department_id)
end
```

This is just a sample. Feel it in with your real field names

Comment: Thank you, I did what you said and it worked, made a controller to extend devise and added sign_up_params as private, and added def new super and def edit super
it seems to be working the new entry had both username and department_id.

Comment: You are welcome and.... you don't need to explicitly mention new/edit/etc. You can just write a very single sign_up_params. Everything else will be mapped to parent by default

Answer (score 1):

Rails since 5.1 or so has a required belongs_to validation with newly generated apps.

You can disable that by:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :department, optional: true
end
```

In this way, you can create users with an empty department first.

Comment: this generates a table entry but no department_id, also i noticed there was no username saved